# 4 GB of RAM, only 2.67 GB usable

Tags: windows-8, memory, performance

My laptop was using a 2 GB RAM and I thought it wasn't enough, so I bought a new 4 GB RAM stick. I have been playing graphic and memory-intensive games, such as Battlefield 4 (the Recommended requirement for RAM is 8 GB, while 4 GB is at Minimum requirements). I have heard from the internet that the BIOS automatically 'locks' part of your available RAM into dedicated or shared video memory.

I checked the display adapter and the page shows:

```
--- Adapter Information ---
Chip Type: Intel (R) HD Graphics Family
DAC Type: Internal
Adapter String: Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000
Bios Information: Intel Video BIOS

Total Available Graphics Memory: 1140 MB
Dedicated Video Memory: 32 MB
System Video Memory: 0 MB
Shared System Memory: 1108 MB
```

As you can see, the Dedicated is at default value while the Shared System Memory is at 1108 MB (which is 1.08 GB) and I'm pretty sure the 1.08 GB is from my main RAM. I have tried accessing BIOS and I couldn't find the option to adjust Shared System Memory. Before this whole 2.67 GB usable RAM happened, I was able to play the game smoothly, but now it becomes more laggy.

I have also searched the internet regarding this issue, but all I got are those either the users were using 32-bit version of Windows (which only lets you use 3 to 3.5 GB of RAM, my system specs is at the end of this description), or about RAM address or something. I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate because I couldn't find the answers for all the searches I've done.

```
--- MY SYSTEM SPECIFICATIONS ---
OS: Windows 8, 64-bit
HDD: 500 GB Hard drive space
CPU: Intel Core i5-2410M, 2.3 GHz (dual core)
RAM: 4 GB (2.67 GB usable)
GPU: GeForce GT520MX 1 GB
```

=== UPDATE ===

As requested by Daniel B, here is a screenshot of the 'Memory' tab in Resource Monitor.

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/11bj9n4.png]

=== UPDATE 2 ===

Based on the 'Memory' tab in Resource Monitor, I see that there is 1368 MB of RAM that is in Hardware Reserved. What does it do? Is it must be reserved so that system would be stable?

Comment: You would need to disable the intel GPU to get that memory back.  Make sure your using the current bios revision

Comment: The new RAM that you bought, is it the same speed as the one that you have removed?

Comment: Please post a screenshot (or rather, a link to one) of the "Memory" tab in Resource Monitor.

Comment: @Ramhound - How do I disable it?

Comment: @StBlade - I don't think so, the previous one was Hynix Korea while the new one is from Kingston.

Comment: @DanielB - Will do.

Comment: @MegaRodeon  Check the manual of your Motherboard and see if it supports the new speed of the RAM. I have had the same problem with running RAM in my laptop which was at a different speed than what the motherboard could handle.  The laptop became sluggish and the RAM was hot really hot to the touch.

Comment: @StBlade - I highly think that it supports it, as when I installed the new RAM stick, the System Properties page reported 4 GB usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. I had the ' *Maximum Memory* ' checked and so this was the problem.

After un-checking and restarted my laptop, Windows recognised all my 8 GB RAM (to add on, I just bought another 4 GB RAM stick).

All I have to do is to:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type *msconfig*  and press Enter
3. Go to the *Boot* tab
4. Click on *Advanced options*
5. Un-check the box *Maximum memory*

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the game is running on Intel GPU instead of dedicated NVIDIA graphics. That would explain poor performance and high RAM usage by Intel GPU.

Open *Control Panel* → *NVIDIA Control Panel* and choose *Manage 3D settings* on the left. Choose your game from the list and choose *High-performance NVIDIA processor* from the list below. Click *Apply* and close the NVIDIA Panel. Check if performance is back to normal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no, it's not working, it still shows 2.67 GB usable. In fact, it has changed to 2.66 GB usable. These two values change from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Generally BIOS would allow disabling integrated graphics card (i. e. i5's one) when dedicated GPU is present, unfortunately though laptops are quite another story.

Laptop BIOS is most of the time quite limited in functionality, especially when this concerns such things as disabling something vital like integrated GPU—the laptop's power management and battery life both depend on integrated GPU being used as much as possible.

All this considered I do not believe you'll be able to disable integrated GPU completely. Even when you're running your game on the dedicated GPU card the integrated one will be used for all the rest and therefore will remain active.

Your best bet is updating to the latest version of BIOS for your laptop—it may contain a setting which will limit memory available for the integrated GPU—or finding some king of overclocking/tweaking utility on your laptop's manufacturer's website with similar setting. There is no guarantee though that any of those exist.

To update your BIOS head to your laptop's manufacturer's website, most probably the instructions and necessary software will be located in the Support or Drivers & Downloads sections of the website. Make sure that you download software compatible with your specific laptop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to know how do I update my BIOS? I'm not so good at IT stuffs and I've heard that updating BIOS is a tricky one. One wrong move and your computer will be useless, is that true?

Comment: See the last paragraph of my updated answer.

Comment: Okay, so I have updated my BIOS to the latest version, but there are still no options or settings to limit memory.

Comment: What about a utility I wrote about? Does your laptop's manufacturer provide one? Oh, I see you've found the solution :) Congrats. That second 4GB is a good choice, too. I personally find that anywhere below 8GB is hardly usable nowadays.

Comment: Yep, I too find it hardly usable for under 8 GB of RAM.