# Hardware reserved memory 8.1GB AMD - MSI - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, motherboard

I am facing reserved hardware memory issue; Its happen automatically, I mean I won't change or update anything in my system. Yesterday I was playing the game then I was check that 90% of memory is used, So I check my computer properties. I Found that 7.98 ram is usable.

I watched many tutorials with different methods nothing is working  like
MSConfig -> Change limit use
Regedit ETC.
I also update my BIOS its, but it did not work - Then I reinstall window still not work

My Config:
X470 GAMING PLUS - Windows 10 Pro N 64Bit - DDR4-2666mhz 8GB*2 - GTX 1050 TI Graphic

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: have you lost? 32bit can only handle 4gb 64bit can use 32gb

Comment: @John - Can you please read the author's question?  The original revision of this question is clear, the author has 2 8 GB modules installed, for a total of 16 GB system memory.  **Their system indicates only 8 GB is usable.**  The author also made it clear they are running a 64-bit verison of WIndows 10 N

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Half of installed RAM is hardware reserved](https://superuser.com/questions/668774/half-of-installed-ram-is-hardware-reserved) and https://superuser.com/questions/1165428/upgrade-memory-from-4gb-to-16gb-but-hardware-reserved-memory-got-8gb?rq=1

Comment: @John - I have 64 GB installed.  My system can use 64 GB.  The author is asking, the reason Windows is unable to use 16 GB, despite 16 GB being installed.  I have no idea what you are talking about with this nonsense about 4 GB being used until applications are loaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1017085/out-of-12-gb-only-8-gb-of-ram-is-usable-in-windows-7-home-edition-64-bit) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/217200/8-gb-ram-installed-only-7-5-gb-usable-windows-7-64-bit) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/738624/4-gb-of-ram-only-2-67-gb-usable)

Comment: I deleted my posts. You did not read them with any intent to understand

Comment: Chances are that a memory stick has become partially unseated but still has enough connected to see the size of the module. Open the machine then remove and reseat the memory modules.